# Access to MYSQL database on Apache

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I have created a Linux server in which I have installed Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

I took all of the website files from Windows and copied them to my Linux machine and the website is up.

I then took the MySQL database (exported) and imported it in MySQL on Linux and MySQL shows the database is there and so are the tables.

So, when I hit the website it looks nothing like it did on Windows. How can I get Apache / website to call my database?

Comment: You need to include more information for this to be a decent question. Please include more information and what you have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I get Apache / website to call my database?

Take the server out to dinner and treat Apache with respect!

Seriously, Apache has nothing to do with the MySQL connection. Settings within the PHP code would handle that. To better understand, this is how a Linux web server running a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) (**L** inux, **A** pache, **M** ySQL, and **P** HP) stack works:

- **Linux** is the base-level operating system.
- **Apache** is the web server.
- **MySQL** is the database server.
- **PHP** is the scripting language that works with Apache.

And PHP is where the connection between your application and database would happen. PHP runs as a module connected to Apache, but Apache has 100% nothing directly to do with it. Apache simply allows PHP to parse PHP code for the server. Past that? There aren't any other connections between the two.

The PHP code should have settings — either hard-coded or in a separate configuration file — that have the MySQL database details stored. The MySQL connection details from your Windows machine need to be changed to match the settings on the Linux server. Specifically, you would be looking for these settings:

- **Host:** Most likely `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
- **Port:** The default MySQL port is `3306`, but this might not be needed in many cases.
- **Database Name:** The name of the database the application needs to use.
- **Username:** The user name that has access to the database indicated above.
- **Password:** The password connected to the username mentioned above.

Comment: Jake -- thank you! That makes sense. Appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Jake while the question is on hold I see the database in mysql along with the tables. For some reason after logging in because there is a log in screen. I can type any password and it works

Comment: telnet "ip address" connection refused

Comment: I can't get on. I don't know what else to do. I try to hit my up address with port 3306 and I get connection refused

Comment: I made and granted user access to the local host and to the remote internal ip address. I ran 2 two commands mysqladmin -u user -p -h ip address and put the password in and shows connection to ip address and I did the same for local host and it shows the connection there as well.

Comment: But I still can't access database on my website. If I type my ip address with port 3306 it downloads a file and once I open that file it tells me connection refused from host. .. Hope this is useful information